# camel restdsl configure modules in the JacksonDataFormat

Tags: apache-camel

when using restdsl in camel, I can see how to configure some feature :

```
    restConfiguration().component("jetty")
            .host("localhost")
            .port("8889")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .dataFormatProperty(....);
```

but cannot see how to configure **modules** specific to jackson. like for these:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need this to get java.time.LocalDate serialized correctly.

Comment: I think part of the answer can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397359/how-to-configure-jackson-objectmapper-for-camel-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same as related here : [How to configure Jackson ObjectMapper for Camel in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397359/how-to-configure-jackson-objectmapper-for-camel-in-spring-boot)

```
@Produces
@Named("json-jackson")
public JacksonDataFormat getjacksonDataFormat() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

    JacksonDataFormat formatter = new JacksonDataFormat(mapper, (Class)null);

    return formatter;
}
```

Because I am using camelcdicontext, the bean is lookedup here. 
I don't know how this could be achieved for the defaultCamelcontext for instance

Comment: another post interesting for date formating with jackson: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates